# What's the throughput of BLE CoC(L2CAP CoC)?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#bluetooth-le-coc

Android 10 has the BLE CoC, and it will enable apps to transfer larger data streams. So What's the max throughput of BLE CoC. 
Is it better than BLE with Data Length Extension(DLE)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoC has nothing to do with LE Length Extension (it's like asking if WebSockets are faster than IPv6). It is just a more convenient way of sending a stream of data than for example with GATT. You will get more or less the same throughput as with GATT notifications/write without response.

An actually good thing with CoC is that the remote device can decrease the incoming throughput if it is not capable of handling the incoming data in time using the Credit system. With GATT notifications or write without response that is not possible and if you follow the GATT standard strictly packets will be dropped if they can't be handled in time.